# Scania problem in engaging gears

Tags: manual-transmission, gears, scania

I am having a problem in engaging gears on my truck series P124 R420.

So I started by diagnosing and found no problem. Then removed the gearbox and changed clutch plate & pressure plate. Then checked all solenoid to see if they open by using two wires connected to a 24 battery, only to find them opening to let air to easy shifter box. Then checked current on the wires that connecting to the solenoids. All had continuous current as we select gears. But found one yellow wire was faulty, the current was not continuous. It flicks as we select gears. Then removed the easy shifter box changed all seals and brochures then re-installed.

Then got inside and did the test from the computer box. As I was testing it gave me some errors: 50, 51, 68, 69, and 73. I don't know what those are!!!  So I started the truck and engaged gears, but still does not engage. I get the same results on the screen: Auto Neutral 1, the gears does show where it's supposed to show that it's engaged.

Please let me know what can this be.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you please tell us what year your P124 was built? Also, I'm going to try and clean up your question a little bit to make it easier to read. I'm assuming you are not a native English speaker. If so, that's no issue.

Comment: Two things to check: ensure all wiring is reconnected (nothing loose or hanging). Second, are you sure you hooked all of them back up correctly  to the right parts? Go back over your work and ensure you did it right.